# Problems populating a html table with an array

Tags: javascript

was hoping to get some help on an issue I've run into (Javascript newbie here!)

I am trying to populate a HTML table with some arrays. I want each value in the various arrays to be on its own row.

So if my arrays are Cases and Deaths, I want cases[1], deaths[1] all on Row 1.

Cases[2], Deaths[2] on Row 2 etc.

The problem I have right now is although the arrays are populating, they are all concatenating/joining onto Row 1 in my table.

They just add onto Row 1, rather than going onto a separate Row (Row 2,3,4 etc.)

How can I do this?

```
    function Table(){
    
    var dResponse = [
    {"state":entered_states.slice(0),"cases":cases.slice(0),"deaths":deaths.slice(0),"drate":drate.slice(0)}
    ];

    var results=document.getElementById('Results');
    results.innerHTML += "<tr><th>State</th><th>Cases</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Death rate</th></tr>";
        for(var obj in dResponse){
        results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+dResponse[obj].state+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].cases+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].deaths+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].drate+"</td></tr>";
    
        }
    }
    window.onload=Table;
```

Comment: add your sample JavaScript object variable you want to construct table from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is something funny going on with your `dresponse` declaration. Slicing at 0 will assign each whole array to only one object, resulting in only one row with four cells containing the entire arrays in one cell. By instead populating dresponse with multiple objects, you can split them up into different cells in different rows. Feel free to inquire further if i'm being unclear, hope this helps! :)

(edit: if you want the arrays to remain the same you can use indexes instead of `shift()`)

Here's what i did (anything before Table() is just for testing):

```js
var entered_states = [],
  cases = [],
  deaths = [],
  drate = [];

(() => {
  var i = 0;
  var fields = [
    entered_states,
    cases,
    deaths,
    drate
  ];
  while (++i <= 3) {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      field.push(`Test${i}`);
    });
  }
})();

function Table() {
  var responseLen = cases.length;
  var dResponse = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < responseLen; i++) {
    dResponse.push({
      "state": entered_states.shift(),
      "cases": cases.shift(),
      "deaths": deaths.shift(),
      "drate": drate.shift()
    });
  }

  var tbody = document.querySelector('#Results tbody');
  var thead = document.querySelector('#Results thead')

  thead.innerHTML += `
             <tr>
               <th>State</th>
               <th>Cases</th>
               <th>Deaths</th>
               <th>Death rate</th>
             </tr>
            `;

  for (var obj in dResponse) {
    tbody.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                  <td> ${dResponse[obj].state} </td>
                  <td> ${dResponse[obj].cases} </td>
                  <td> ${dResponse[obj].deaths}</td>
                  <td> ${dResponse[obj].drate}</td>
                </tr>
              `;
  }
}
window.onload = Table;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="Results">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi BjarkeBr - this is great! It works exactly as I was hoping! I never knew about .shift() [newbie here!] so its given me some readings to do!

If you don't mind, I have 2 final queries I was hoping you could push me in the right direction for; 

1) how do I add a table border? I tried adding into the <body> tag as per normal but it replaces the data completely. 

2) is it possible to list the results in the table in descending order based on one of the arrays, for example # of cases?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: 1) table border i would consider a stylistic concern, for this reason i would put this in the css stylesheet. If youre only working in a single file project with an attached script this can be inlined using the `style` tag. Example : 
`<style> #Results { border: 1px solid black; } </style>`
You can learn more about css at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS 


2) It is absolutely possible, you would have to sort the array of objects (`dresponse`).  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: For the `compare` function which declares the logic behind the sort, you could do something like `function compare(a, b) { return a["drate"] - b["drate"]; }`. Where drate would decide the order. Reversing the direction would just require flipping the arithmetic operation. I highly advise you to read more about comparison functions, and think about adding some error handling should you use this snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `tbody` before all rows. when you try to append `<tr>` it creates a new `tbody` for each row

```js
  function Table(){
    
    var dResponse = [
    {"state":"test","cases":"test2","deaths":"test3","drate":"test4"},
    {"state":"test","cases":"test2","deaths":"test3","drate":"test4"},
    ];

    var results=document.getElementById('results-body');
        for(var obj in dResponse){
        results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+dResponse[obj].state+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].cases+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].deaths+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].drate+"</td></tr>";
    
        }
    }
    window.onload=Table;
```

```html
<table id="Results">
  <thead>
  <tr><th>State</th><th>Cases</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Death rate</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

if you want to improve your code:

- check if dResponse has a property using `hasOwnProperty`
- store the results in a separate variable and inject the results at the end of the loop

```js
function createTable() {
  let dResponse = [
    {'state': 'test', 'cases': 'test2', 'deaths': 'test3', 'drate': 'test4'},
    {'state': 'test', 'cases': 'test2', 'deaths': 'test3', 'drate': 'test4'},
  ];

  let results = document.getElementById('results-body');
  let html = '';
  for (let obj in dResponse) {
    if(dResponse.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
      html += '<tr><td>' + dResponse[obj].state + '</td><td>' + dResponse[obj].cases + '</td><td>' + dResponse[obj].deaths + '</td><td>' + dResponse[obj].drate + '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
  results.innerHTML = html;
}
window.onload = createTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Izik. 

I've tried your initial advice but am still having some issues with no new row. It looks like if I change my initial let statement, 

dResponse statement from what I originally had state":entered_states.slice(0),"cases":cases.slice(0) etc. 
to yours it does work

My question would be then, how can I grab all values from the array then? The code doesn't seem to work if I use 
  var dResponse = [
  {"state":entered_states.slice(1),"cases":cases.slice(0),"deaths":deaths.slice(0),"drate":drate.slice(0)},];

Comment: @Valador1988 i need more information about entered_states,cases,deaths & drate. it's a single value? array? if you provide full example I may help you